# elastic object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new in Unity and need some help, would greatly appreciate any answers!

I'm trying to create an elastic plane, which I want to stretch by dragging. I want to stretch the whole plane by the x-axis using ctrl+left mouse button and by the y-axis using alt+left mouse button. 
Then I want to stretch single polygons which are along the border of the plane by using just the left mouse button and dragging in any direction.

So far I've managed to stretch the whole plane with either left or right mouse button, using the script beneath, but I haven't been able to limit how far it can be stretched so I would appreciate any tips on how to do that as well. For stretching single polygons I've looked into the cloth modifier and tried to attach movable objects, but haven't been able to make it work at all. 
Thank you for any help!

```
public GameObject elasticobject;
public float sizingFactor = 0.1f;
private GameObject lastSpawn = null;
private float startSize;
private float startX;

void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Vector3 size = elasticobject.transform.localScale;
        size.x = startSize + (Input.mousePosition.x - startX) * sizingFactor;
        elasticobject.transform.localScale = size;
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        Vector3 size = elasticobject.transform.localScale;
        size.y = startSize + (Input.mousePosition.y - startX) * sizingFactor;
        elasticobject.transform.localScale = size;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Mathf.Clamp is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

As Draco has said, Mathf.Clamp is useful for this sort of thing.

```
public GameObject elasticobject;
public float sizingFactor = 0.1f;
private GameObject lastSpawn = null;
private float startSize;
private float startX;

private float limitX;
private float limitY;

void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Vector3 size = elasticobject.transform.localScale;
        size.x = Mathf.Clamp(
            startSize + (Input.mousePosition.x - startX) * sizingFactor, 
            0, limitX);
        elasticobject.transform.localScale = size;
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        Vector3 size = elasticobject.transform.localScale;
        size.y = Mathf.Clamp(
            startSize + (Input.mousePosition.y - startX) * sizingFactor, 
            0, limitY);
        elasticobject.transform.localScale = size;
    }
}
```

I've added in some limits for X and Y for you. I don't understand exactly what you are doing, and the use of StartX is a bit mystifying, especially as it shows up in the Y-axis section.

When doing this kind of re-scaling, its more useful to increase by a percentage rather than a fixed amount. Otherwise very large planes will show very little change at all relative to its size.

```
private float multFactor = 0.01f;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Vector3 size = elasticobject.transform.localScale;
        size.x = Mathf.Clamp(
            size.x *= 1 + multFactor,
            0, limitX);
        elasticobject.transform.localScale = size;
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        Vector3 size = elasticobject.transform.localScale;
        size.x = Mathf.Clamp(
            size.y *= 1 + multFactor,
            0, limitY);
        elasticobject.transform.localScale = size;
    }
}
```

Another thing to be careful of here is that you've essentially defined the same method with slight variations in two different areas (one for X, one for Y). This is probably fine for just the two but if you find yourself defining a method three or more times, you are best off using a single method that takes additional arguments. This way, if you want to change something you will only have to change it in one spot.

I haven't actually run these to see if they work, so they might need some small modifications.